# Change link location of "create" button flask-admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

I have this flask admin interface, but I want to change the behavior of the `Create` link, so I can link to my own creation interface instead of letting flask admin making a create form for me. What would also work is adding another link, next to `With Selected`, which redirects to another page.  It's complicated geometrical data, so I need a completely different data creating interface, `Products` is just an example.

[image]

I would really prefer not to add another admin template, so it would be nice if it could be done in python.

After trying out for quite some time, I managed to find this solution, which does exactly what I want:

```
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
admin = Admin(app)

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

db.create_all()

class SuperHackyFlaskAdminRedirectFakeException(Exception):
    pass

@app.errorhandler(SuperHackyFlaskAdminRedirectFakeException)
def handle_fake_errors(error):
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'this is the index'

class ProductView(ModelView):
    column_display_pk = True

    def redirect_to_index_from_admin(_):
        raise SuperHackyFlaskAdminRedirectFakeException()

    create_form = redirect_to_index_from_admin

admin.add_view(ProductView(Product, db.session))
```

As you might see, it's really hacky though, and I would prefer to find a better solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `create_view` method of `ProductView`.

```
class ProductView(ModelView):
    column_display_pk = True

    @expose('/new/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def create_view(self):
        # render your view here
        return "Hello World"
```